# Angular array and ng-repeat for ratio group

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a questionnaire which I can fill directly in the app's variables, due I don't have any database in this little project. The questionaire is made by 20 questions and I am using radio buttons for selecting the answer. At end end of the questionaire I will need to show the selected answers, for this I did the scope object **testResult**

Initially, I was thinking to fill all 20 questions and radio variables manually, but I saw a ng-repeat angular function that can be helpful, and will like to know if I can use it in the this case.

I may be storing the initial values of each radio group inside and array, and then print them in the view using ng-repeat. I don't really have a clue where to start.

The next are piece of code related to my project.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="qs01" ng-model="testResult.qs01" value="1">
            Question One.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="qs01" ng-model="testResult.qs01" value="2">
            Question Two.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="qs01" ng-model="testResult.qs01" value="3">
            Question Three.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="qs01" ng-model="testResult.qs01" value="4">
            Question Four.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="qs01" ng-model="testResult.qs01" value="5">
            Question Five.
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**App**

```
// Test Result Object
$scope.testResult = {};
```

What I need to repeat is:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="qs01" ng-model="testResult.qs01" value="Question Variable">
        Question Variable
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting different labels on each radio. But each radio is an option for the value of the *same question*.

You need to include radio options array to use ng-repeat. So you could do:

`$scope.qs01Options = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow'];`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>Question One.</label>
        <input ng-repeat="opt in qs01Options" type="radio" name="qs01" ng-model="testResult.qs01" value="{{opt}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

This repeats the options for **1 question**. The name stays the same because that's how radio inputs for the same field work in a form.

If you want to have multiple questions, each with multiple options, you need to use an array of arrays; each object would hold an array of options for that question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tasted and it works, just... I notice that all ratios are in the same position. What I want to achieve is to repeat all the box that contains each radio , and change the label and the variable with the repeated option. Can this be achivied in the same way?

**I updated the question, if you want to have a look.**

Comment: I understood!! And it worked :D  ... I moved the ng-repeat and it worked for the radio container. this is the code I used:

`<div class="radio" ng-repeat="opt in qs01Opt">
       <label><input type="radio" name="qs01" ng-model="testResult.qs01" value="{{opt}}">
        {{opt}}.
       </label>
      </div>`

**Thank you once again!**